# If a country withdraws your nationality and asked you to leave. Does they gave you a passport without nationality to leave?

Tags: stateless-persons

If your country Govenment withdraws your nationality for any reason; and asked you to leave the country. Would the Govenment provide you with a passport without nationality to travel out side and never come back? Or What?!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Perhaps a better question to ask is can a government revoke your citizenship (except for countries that have become defunct)? And, if they do, what happens to you? After all, you don’t need a passport to be deported. You may need one to be allowed into another country depending on your status. In the US, a natural born citizen can not be denaturalized. Others may be for only certain reasons based on this website https://www.uscis.gov/policy-manual/volume-12-part-l-chapter-2  .

Comment: I think you should ask on others of our sister site (check the icon on top right). Law maybe? There is an UN convention forbidding it (and in general to reduce state-less people, which cause many problems [e.g. how to deport them, if the other country will not allow this person to enter?). On the other hand, it happens on unrest times (when state are also more prone to "forget laws"). Because it is used on special circumstance, there is no rule. You may be arrested (and keep in prison), deported (with just a document that tell your identity, not your nationality, or often none [expatriates])

Comment: One note to take from the website is that they make a distinction between having your application withdrawn or your certificate canceled versus having your citizenship revoked. It would primarily appear this is done when you obtained your citizenship through fraud, deception, or other illegal means. And, natural born citizens can voluntarily be expatriated through their own actions like denouncing their citizenship or treason.

Comment: To the other comments I would add that "drow" is not a standard English verb.  I can guess at what verb you meant to use, and the meaning of your question is more or less clear, but it would be much clearer if you could identify the right word to use instead of "drow."

Comment: @phoog I can't. I have absolutely no idea what "drow" means in this context or even what language it might be.

Comment: @MichaelHampton my comment was addressed to Mark, not to you.

Comment: According to the Oxford English Dictionary, drow is an English word but now only south-western dialect. As a verb it means to dry.

Comment: I edited the question to what I assume it means.

Comment: No, a Stateless passport (historically called a [Nansen passport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nansen_passport)), will generally **not** be issued where the person is **not** allowed to return to the issuing country. Such a condition may exist where a person becomes stateless under **Artical 8 (2)(b)** of the [Convention on the Reduction of Statelessness of 1961-08-30](https://www.unhcr.org/ibelong/wp-content/uploads/1961-Convention-on-the-reduction-of-Statelessness_ENG.pdf): **where the nationality has been obtained by misrepresentation or fraud** (which I assume **drow** means).

Comment: @MarkJohnson nobody's been calling them Nansen passports since the middle of the last century.

Comment: @phoog Thus the word **historicaly**, for those that are interested on how stateless passports have envolved. There the **main** principle was definded (that is still valid today): the passport is a garantie that the issuing country will allow the stateless person back.

Comment: For historical purposes, there was an infamous wave of semi-forced emigration in 1968 in Poland, people who were asked to leave the country were stripped of the citizenship and were issued a [Travel Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_document_(Poland)), which explicitly stated that the person is NOT a Polish citizen. Effectively, it was a one-way passport.

Comment: East Germany issued, since September 1968, an  [Identitätsbescheinigung](http://www.runde-ecke-leipzig.de/sammlung/index.php?inv=14978) (Certificate of Identity) both for persons whose documents were considered invalid **or** had been de-nationalised (citizenship marked with '---'). A corresponding visa was then stamped on the last page.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi AFAIK it is valid under international law to strip someone of his nationality as long as he has other citizenship so he does not become stateless. In fact it routinely happens when a citizen of a country that does not accept dual citizenship acquires another citizenship. But it is indeed against international law to strip someone of their only/last citizenship.

Comment: @SJuan76: right. Probably the "without nationality" on the question made me to think the second case (so to the person), but that "without nationality" was linked to passport.

Comment: @SJuan76 This is not generally correct. The relevent Convention (not law) **does** forsee's conditions (see quoted **Artical 8 (2)(b)** above). That is why the term **avoid** is always used in this context.

Comment: @SJuan76 Although international law primarily affects the interactions between countries and can't necessarily be used in a domestic court to force a country to issue identification documents.